# Identify duplicate values from three text files in java

Tags: java, while-loop, duplicates, do-while

Your program is required to search through the three files to find a credit card number used at all three stores. Then output what that number is.

You may follow the rough pseudo code below. Note that it is incomplete and that you may be required to interpret missing parts. Properly document and comment your code.

Main Method: Process First Store
declare and initialize a Boolean variable match to false
read a credit card number from the file
while match is false, and the credit card number is not null
pass the credit card number to the method that processes the second store. If it returns true set match to true, otherwise repeat from (2)
if match is true or the credit card number is null then finish the program. Depending on the value of match, output the matching result or indicate no match found.

This is the question , I have written the code but the problem is its comparing one line by another line in the other text file , not taking only one value then comparing it with whole values in another file. Please Help , a small idea would also be appreciated . Please help me in the concept!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Boolean match = false;
        File file = new File("/Users/User/Desktop/CreditCards/creditCards1.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String credit_card_number = "";
        while (scan.hasNextLine() && !match ) {
             credit_card_number = scan.nextLine();
             match = second_Store(credit_card_number);
            System.out.println(credit_card_number);


        } scan.close();
        if (match == true){
            ;
        }else
            System.out.println(credit_card_number);
        System.out.println(match);

    }







    public static Boolean second_Store(String creditCard) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Boolean match = false;
        File file = new File("/Users/User/Desktop/CreditCards/creditCards2.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String credit_card_number;String toCompare = creditCard;

        do{
            credit_card_number = scan.nextLine();
            if (credit_card_number.equals(creditCard)){
                third_Store(credit_card_number);
                System.out.println(credit_card_number);
                match = true;
            }else
                continue;


        }while(match && scan.hasNextLine());
        return match;

    }

    public static Boolean third_Store(String creditCard) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Boolean match = false;
        File file = new File("/Users/User/Desktop/CreditCards/creditCards3.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String credit_card_number;
        do{
            credit_card_number = scan.nextLine();
            if(credit_card_number.equals(creditCard)){
                match = true;
                System.out.println(credit_card_number);
            }
            else
                continue;

            } while (match && scan.hasNextLine());
        return match;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple program to find a line in 3 files (currently "path1", "path2" and "path3") that compiles if you put the correct package:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Common line: " + getCommonLine(new File("path1"), new File("path2"), new File("path3")));
    }
    
    /** Gets a common line in the specified files */
    private static String getCommonLine(/* Any amount of file arguments */ File... files) throws IOException {
        /* A list of the file's lines */
        List<Set<String>> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
        /* The combined file's lines */
        Set<String> allLines = new HashSet<>();

        /* Get the lines in all files */
        for(File file : files) {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
            fileLines.add(new HashSet<String>(lines));
            allLines.addAll(lines);
        }

        /* Loop through the combined lines */
        for(String line : allLines) {
            /* Check if all files contain the line */
            boolean result = true;
            for(Set<String> otherFileLines : fileLines) {
                if(!otherFileLines.contains(line)) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            if(result) {
                return line;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I didn't have time to run it though so it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know about Sets:

- read each store data into a Set, which will then contain all unique numbers of that store
- iterate set 2 and remove all values not contained in set 1
- iterate set 3 and remove all numbers not contained in set 2
- set 3 should then contain only numbers found in all 3 stores

Comment: so you mean to add all the values in the sets , then compare the sets together to get the duplicate values?

Comment: Let me rephrase the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Also, this is just an idea. I'm sure there are many viable strategies.

Comment: the thing is you could be right but i would need to specify the condition in the question , i am a bit confused in while loop that i wrote. Do you have any idea like how do i read one value and compare it with the other values in other file . only  like (one to many).